# Start and stop recording with button click

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making a simple android app for recording sound. I have a startRecording() and stopRecording() methods. Now I implemented a ToggleButton named "Touch to record" so as you can already imagine, when the button is checked, you have to hold the record button to record sound and when the button is on "off" you have to click to start and then click to stop.

This is the current code:

```
touchToRecord.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                recBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        {
                            recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
                            chTimer.start();
                            chTimer.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            startRecording();
                        }
                        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                        {
                            recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn);
                            chTimer.stop();
                            stopRecording();
                            nameAlert();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                });
            }
            else
            {
                //onClickListener
            }
        }

    });
```

Now I'm not sure how to make the onClickListener. If I try to do it like this:

```
recBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });
```

It won't work because it underlines setOnClickListener and says:

> The method setOnClickListener (View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

Also, one more thing after I get this working; how do I check if the method is already running with if statement? I want to do something like this:

```
if (startRecording == isRunning)
{
    stopRecording();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem!

I avoided using onClickListener by setting onClick in XML and then just creating the method. Here's the code:

```
public void recordBtnClick(View v){
    final ToggleButton touchToRecord = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tBtn1);
    final ImageButton recBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.id.recButton);
    if (touchToRecord.isChecked() == false)
    {
        if (recorder == null)
        {
            recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
            chTimer.start();
            chTimer.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            startRecording();
        }
        else if (recorder != null)
        {
            recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn);
            chTimer.stop();
            stopRecording();
            nameAlert();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //DO NOTHING
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try android toggle button. Please see more information on:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Comment: I am using this exact toggle button (not the switch)